# How to show vi mode in bash?

Tags: macos, bash, vi

I'm on Yosemite, using vi mode in bash (`set -o vi` in .bash_profile) and I want to have the prompt indicate if I'm in edit or command mode.  I looked around and found that this feature has been implemented in bash 4.3 (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116385/46076) and can be turned on by setting the variable `show-mode-in-prompt` to `on`.  I installed bash 4.3 using homebrew following [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116385/46076).  Now, when I execute `bash --version` I see `GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0)` and `brew info readline` returns `readline: stable 6.3.8 (bottled)` so it looks like I'm using the correct versions.  However, when I execute `set show-mode-in-prompt on` or add it to ~/.inputrc based on the [readline manual](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC10), the prompt still doesn't change based on the vi mode.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I didn't do anything wrong and an additional reboot is all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, although `bash --version` shows 4.3.42(1)-release, `echo $BASH_VERSION` still showing 3.*, then I realize the default bash haven't been changed, please refer to this link: [terminal - Update bash to version 4.0 on OSX - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx)

Answer (score 0):

put bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on' into bash_profile ;) don't thanks me.