# Update bash to version 4.0 on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

Is it possible to actually update bash to version 4.0 in OSX Yosemite?

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
```

This [article](http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/) and this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/857250/how-to-update-bash-on-mac-os-x-yosemite) refer to the same question, but they install a new shell side-by-side with the old one. Is there a way to directly update the old bash shell?

Comment: There is no need to do that. In fact, it is always a good idea to keep the original one. Two or more versions of bash can be installed at the same time, and you can set whichever one you like to be the default

Comment: Essentially Apple's Software Update would be responsible for changing the version of BASH on the system, like it did with the update to BASH for Shellshock.  So unless Apple provides an update then there is no direct way to update to the latest version of GNU BASH that came installed as part of OS X.  An indirect way would be to download it yourself, by one means or another, and instal it and then set it as your default shell.  Whether or not you choose to remove the shipped version or Apple updated version, that's up to you.

Comment: For anyone else like me coming here from Google, starting with macOS Catalina (10.15) you can set the default shell to zsh pretty easily. zsh will be the default shell in macOS going forward. Many similar features to bash. And most importantly it's an up-to-date version. Steps here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

Comment: Probably in Yosemite (10.10) you can, but in El Capitan (10.11) System Integrity Protection https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204899 will prevent you modifying /bin and thus /bin/bash

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Apple will not update Bash, because the latest version is licensed under GPLv3, which Apple cannot use. They have updated most of their other shells though. ZSH for example is mostly up to date.

References:

After a bit of research, this seems like the primary issue:

- https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#Tivoization

> When people distribute User Products that include software under GPLv3, section 6 requires that they provide you with information necessary to modify that software. User Products is a term specially defined in the license; examples of User Products include portable music players, digital video recorders, and home security systems.

This would require that otherwise closed-source software, have its GPL'd portions be made modifiable by the public, which would obviously be an issue for Apple.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68950/discussion-on-answer-by-william-t-froggard-update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx).

Comment: This explanation does not make sense.  Shipping a GPL (v3 or otherwise) binary does not mean that the rest of the OS would need to be released. The rest of the OS does not *link* to `bash`. The "Tivoization" clause might explain why `bash` can't be updated on, say, an Apple TV, but not really on a desktop Mac.  Furthermore, "GPL'd portions" already would need to be made modifiable by the public; v3 would not change that.  I *would believe* that the *patents* clause of GPL v3 would be sufficient to deter Apple from touching GPL v3 code.

Comment: Why would that be an issue for Apple? Bash is already open source (all versions ≥1.14 are available via GNU @ http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ & the version included with macOS (currently v3.2) is available via Apple @ https://opensource.apple.com/source/bash/), but it could be modified regardless.

Comment: @tjt263 It's about the differences between GPLv3 and GPLv2, which the version Apple uses, is still licensed under.

Comment: Right, Bash3.2 is licensed under GPLv2. Bash4.x is licensed under GPLv3. So what? You said: *"Apple will not update Bash, because the latest version is licensed under GPLv3, which **Apple cannot use**."* Why can't they? *"This would require that otherwise closed-source software, have its GPL'd portions be made **modifiable by the public**, which would **obviously be an issue for Apple**."* Why is that an issue? They do that already. It's already modifiable by the public. All software is. Especially when it's FOSS and they're giving away the source code on their site to anyone who wants it.

Comment: @jamesdlin What exactly is the patents clause that keeps Apple away from Bash 4?

Comment: @FranklinYu Hm, I don't remember exactly what I was thinking, but maybe "you may not initiate litigation (including a cross-claim or counterclaim in a lawsuit) alleging that any patent claim is infringed by making, using, selling, offering for sale, or importing the Program or any portion of it"

Comment: Downvoting this. OP asks whether end-users can upgrade the version of bash that is installed, but this answer explains why Apple doesn't ship MacOS with the latest version. This answer does not engage with OP's question, which is a "how-to" not a "why." (Although, FWIW, this answer _does_ answer the "why" question accurately.)

Answer (score 120):

As @William said in his answer, Apple does not provide bash 4 due to GPL restrictions. You can install bash 4+ however and also can make it your default shell (including for Terminal and [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/)) by doing the following.

#### Install Bash 4 via Homebrew

First install the newer version of bash. There are various ways of doing that, I prefer Homebrew.

- Install Homebrew as described at http://brew.sh.
- Install bash using `brew install bash`.

Bash 4 is now available on your PATH (assuming Homebrew bin is on your path). However, it is **not** yet your default shell. You can find where it is located by running `which bash`. In my case it is at `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

#### Using Bash 4

Since it is on your PATH, you can start a Bash 4 session with just `bash` or it can be used in scripts by using a [Shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang).

For example, this will use a specific bash instance.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
...your script...
```

This will use the first bash on the PATH.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...your script...
```

You can also set the bash path for specific profiles in Terminal/iTerm2 using the steps described in @user136952's answer.

#### Making Bash 4 the default

As mentioned above, after installing Bash 4 is still not the default shell. To make bash the default you need to do two more steps.

First, add the Bash 4 path to your `/etc/shells` file so that it is an allowed login shell. As described in [/etc/shells](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/shells), this file has the list of valid login shells. After adding the new bash path my `/etc/shells` looks like the following:

```
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Next we use chsh to make it your default shell. So any sessions for that user will use that shell. You can read more about this in [Change the Shell in Mac OS X Terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/), but the actual command is very straightforward.

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Now the new bash is our default login shell. If you open Terminal or iTerm2 and run `bash --version` you should see the new version. Note the "License GPLv3+" which is why Apple doesn't bundle it with macOS.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: He mentioned that he specifically doesn't want the install-side-by-side option.

Comment: Based on article/thread he linked to I think he really meant "not default" by saying not side-by-side. My answer makes 4 the default so 3 is no longer seen. The fact that the old bash happens to still be taking up some disk space doesn't seem like a big issue to me.

Comment: +1 by me. Yes, OP doesn’t want this, but the question belongs to the community and if this helps other people, awesome. It might not get a check as the answer the OP selects, but that doesn’t make it a bad answer.

Comment: @studgeek, are there any long-term side-effects to making bash4 the default shell for the root user on Mac OS X?  I ran the chsh command but am going to attempt to remember that if things go haywire, I need to change it back.  However, it would help put my mind at ease knowing the answer to this question.  Thank you!

Comment: On High Sierra, `sudo chpass -s /usr/local/bin/bash` changes my shell for root/sudo _only._ To change for my regular login, I must run the command without `sudo`. This might be an Active Directory thing; I’m not sure.

Comment: Instead of using the `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` shebang, look into using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/what-is-the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash)). This will run the script with whatever version of bash is reachable by the environment that's launching the script, i.e. whatever `which bash` returns. It's a more portable solution that using specific paths. We can't expect other users to install bash through homebrew.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Yes, good catch. I shouldn't have stuck sudo in there. I've updated it.

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin, I originally used a specific path because I wanted to show how to use it explicitly. I've updated the examples to have both.

Comment: @harperville I shouldn't have had the sudo before the chsh. Running it with chsh just changes it for the current user (which seems safer as you suggest).

Comment: @studgeek Apologies, my comment was aimed at other passing readers, but thank you for updating the answer! I like the `env` method because it makes it easier to reuse scripts between macOS and Linux, e.g. between host and VMs.

Comment: `chsh` was the critical missing step for me. Thank you.

Comment: At step 1, for most people after `brew install bash`, the command `which bash` would simply point to the bash 3.4 version installed by default in macOS, not the version you just installed with homebrew.

Comment: One of the main points of homebrew is that it installs executables in `/usr/`. Doing `sudo` and editing `/etc/shells` seems out of place, it would be like editing `/etc/paths` directly for all your executables instead of echoing to `$PATH` in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: I wash to keep my default shell to zsh. But I want to use new bash versions for my bash script. Is it possible on Mac?

Comment: A nice step by step tutorial from 2019 can also be found at https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba

Comment: minor note this is now at version 5 and in my brew install it set it right on the path.

Comment: @user I also want to keep ZSH as my default shell on macOS Ventura. So after installing the latest Bash version with `brew install bash`, I have put the **path** to the newly installed Bash (on Apple Silicon machines it is `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`) in the `/etc/shells` file  **BEFORE** the default `/bin/bash` line. So this way the new Bash will be used first: you can test it with `which bash` or executing `bash --version` to ensure that the new Bash is used.

Answer (score 85):

Is it possible to actually update bash to version 4.0 in OSX Yosemite? Yes.

1. Download / Install homebrew http://brew.sh/
   by running this command in terminal.

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. Quit and reopen your terminal. then type

   ```
   brew install bash
   ```
3. Change the default shell via the terminal gui with the literal path of your new bash (EDIT: I have yet to find a CLI way that works )

[image]

Is it possible to actually update bash to ***Apple’s provided bash*** version 4.0 in OSX Yosemite?

EDIT: No. Not in the way the op is asking. E.g upgrade the current install by way of replacing itself.  It has been noted in other answers that Apple has not updated bash due to licensing issues. However downloading an updated and separate version of bash and using it as your default shell is the canonical solution, for most interpreters. Take python for example. You do not upgrade 2.7 to 3.5 you download a separate version and change your default.

Comment: You can set the default via the CLI with: `sudo chpass -s /usr/local/bin/bash`. Note: It's best to point to the symlink in `/usr/local/bin/` that way Brew can handle upgrades without having to change your environment each time.

Comment: what are the risks of going with a non-Apple shell?

Comment: `sudo bash -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells'` then `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash` will set the default shell for the terminal

Comment: @3pitt There's very little risk in installing a newer `bash` to `/usr/local/bin/bash` because it leaves the system `/bin/bash` alone. So any system dependencies on `bash 3` will be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

The side-by-side install with an update to your shell (via chsh or the GUI) will fail for scripts. Scripts often use `env bash`, which reverts to the OS X bash version. So, what you want may not be the complete update of bash, but a side-by-side install *that always returns the newer version of bash* (i.e. even when `env` is invoked).

So, to handle this:

1) install bash via Homebrew, as the other commenters have posted

2) set your login shell to this new version (via the GUI or chsh command as others have posted)

3) set `/usr/local/bin` (or the path to the new bash version) ahead of `/bin` on your $PATH variable, by adding this to your `~/.bash_profile`: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: This will break scripts that expect bash version 3 - ie Apple supplied scripts - you need to use sde by side

Comment: A fair point. Been running like this for some time now and no issues. Maybe Apple provides the full path in its scripts or it just hasn't hit a snag. For apple system level scripts, i.e. not from a shell, it never calls the `.bash_profile` anyway, so it would only impact something you run directly in a terminal anyway.

Comment: @Mark I can't think of an instance where v ≥4.x would break a script written for v ≤3.x. Can you?

Answer (score 2):

You can install another version of Bash without homebrew

- Go to [GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)
- Download the version you want ([here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/))
- And follow the steps here: https://gist.github.com/samnang/1759336

  Download and install bash version you want 
  Replace X.X (in bash-X.X) with the version you want e.g 4.4

  > ```
  > curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-X.X.tar.gz
  > tar xzf bash-X.X.tar.gz
  > cd bash-X.X
  > ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install
  > ```
  >
  > Add the new shell to the list of legit shells
  >
  > ```
  > sudo bash -c "echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /private/etc/shells"
  > ```
  >
  > Change the shell for the user
  >
  > ```
  > chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
  > ```
  >
  > Check for Bash 4 and /usr/local/bin/bash...
  >
  > ```
  > echo $BASH && echo $BASH_VERSION
  > ```

  You might want to add an alias if you want the bash command to use it.
  Place in your ~/.bash_profile

  ```
  alias bash="/usr/local/bin/bash"
  ```

Comment: This strikes me as a good approach, but I wonder this: Why would one not simply *replace* the antique `/bin/bash`? Is it because it's needed for compatibility with other "antique" software Apple distributes in MacOS?

Comment: This will dump all the installation directories into `/usr/local`. If you'd rather have them organized in a `bash-X.X` directory, append `/bash-X.X` to the prefix parameter in the `./configure` command.

Comment: @Seamus you're not allowed to modify the `/bin` directory unless you disable `SIP`.

Answer (score 0):

For M1 Macs -

You can update bash by doing

`brew install bash`

assuming that you already have Home-brew. This will install the latest version of bash. You can check you installation by running -

`brew info bash`

To update the shell, simply restart the terminal and check the version of bash using -

`bash --version`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this any different from the answer for Intel Macs? Also, step 1 should be "install homebrew".

Comment: I have not worked on intel macs but M1s have an older version of bash so I put this here. Also, my answer does mention "assuming homebrew is installed".

Comment: this worked well