# update/upgrade bash without homebrew

Tags: command-line, bash

I have MacOS ***El Capitan*** - about bash it is:

```
bash --version
... version: 3.2.57(1)-release
...
```

I did realise the `mapfile` command is not available in that bash release. I already did do research and the most obvious solution is upgrade bash - but the 95% of tutorials are based with Homebrew - therefore I can't use it because my macos is very old.

Do the same approach **without** Homebrew exists the following:

- [Update bash to version 4.0 on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339706/348694)
- [Install new bash version on MacOS without homebrew](https://www.cyber-tec.org/2018/01/11/install-new-bash-version-on-macos-without-homebrew/)

But all is about `make` and `install`. Now according with my experience in Linux after to read a good amount of tutorials about installing and updating/upgrating sofware - it is better avoid manual installation and use repositories instead - for macos is homebrew ...

So, exists other way to update/upgrade bash without a manual make/install approach? through a `.dmg` file for example

Even if it would be the unique other non-homebrew approach:

- is safe? - perhaps it asks for something that my current macos does not have and all go wrong
- is possible again do any future upgrade in peace? for example from 4.0 to 5.0 and go on ...

Comment: You can use MacPorts which has better support for older macOS versions.

Comment: The only ways are compile yourself using make or use a package manager - note that Homebrew does not support El Capitain (as note Macports does support all versions back to Tiger)

Comment: @nohillside time to do a new research :) thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @mmmmmm yes, homebrew only offers supports to the 2 latest releases - not sure if that change it - time to use Macports. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) instead of Homebrew, which supports older versions of macOS as well. See https://www.macports.org/install.php for how to install it.

The [MacPorts bash package](https://ports.macports.org/port/bash/) can then be installed with

```
sudo port install bash
```