# In Terminal, using the "touch" command to mass create consecutive files with leading zero's, with bash, produces different results than zsh

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

In **Terminal**, I prefer to use **bash** as my default shell. Issuing the command `touch File_{01..10}.txt` produces these results:

*File_1.txt,
File_10.txt,
File_2.txt,
File_3.txt,
File_4.txt,
File_5.txt,
File_6.txt,
File_7.txt,
File_8.txt,
File_9.txt*

As you can see, there are no leading zeros in the file names.

However, using `zsh`, the same command `touch File_{01..10}.txt` produces these results:

*File_01.txt,
File_02.txt,
File_03.txt,
File_04.txt,
File_05.txt,
File_06.txt,
File_07.txt,
File_08.txt,
File_09.txt,
File_10.txt*

As you can see, `zsh` produces the desired results with the leading zeros.

Is there anyway I can configure `bash` to produce the same results as `zsh` for use with the `touch` command?

Comment: Some options for adding leading zeros in sequences are discussed [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/how-to-create-a-sequence-with-leading-zeroes-using-brace-expansion). Note that one possible answer is installing a [modern version of `bash`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx).

Comment: This is not related to _touch_, but to the way your shells do the brace expansion. You can also test it by doing a `echo {01..10}`. This may depend on the shell version: My `bash` (4.4) also produces the expansion with leading zeroes, like zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bash version included with macOS is quite old (3.2.57 as of Monterey 12.3.1) and doesn't honor leading zeros when expanding `{01..10}`, but newer versions of Bash do (from `man bash`):

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are
> either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment,
> is an  integer.   When integers  are  supplied,  the expression
> expands to each number between x and y, inclusive.  Supplied integers
> may be prefixed with 0 to force each term to have the same width.
> When either x or y begins with a zero, the shell attempts to force all
> generated terms to contain the same number of digits, zero-padding
> where  necessary.

I'd recommend that you install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and then Bash (5.1.16 as of this writing), and configure Terminal to use that version instead (correct the path below accordingly):

[image]

Comment: Perfect… works like a charm.  Does this mean that when I'm creating and saving shell scripts, the shebang now should be `#! /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash`?

Comment: Good question... `#! /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash` will break when `bash` is updated. I would either recommend `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. The former points to a symlink to the current version of `bash`, the latter selects `bash` according to `PATH`, which is a more robust approach but, for it to work as expected, you must edit `PATH` in `.bash_profile` and prepend `/usr/local/bin` to it: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Without installing a package manager and then a newer version of your shell, you could work with the tools you have. Using the builtin command `printf` you could-

```
touch $(printf "file_%02d.txt " {1..10})
```

You could also use the external command `jot`-

```
touch $(jot -s " " -w 'file_%02d.txt' 10)
```

Now if you wanted to use the bash5 sequence expression `{START..END[..INCREMENT]}` then -

```
jot -s " " -w 'file_%02d.txt' 4 2 10
```

where 4 equal the number of times printed, 2 equals the increment, and 10 equal the maximum value.

Of course after all, you could use `zsh` within your "default" shell to do the lifting-

```
zsh -c 'touch file_{01..10}.txt'
```